# An error when integrate Ruby script with Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-6

I am new to Ruby and Ruby on rails in general!

I tried multiple solutions to solve this problem but no hope!

This's the original Ruby code below that I've been trying to integrate into my Ruby on Rails crud app.

```
text = "Text"

canvas = Magick::Image.new(1000, 1000) { self.background_color = "yellow" }
    gc = Magick::Draw.new
    gc.pointsize(50)
    gc.text(30, 70, text.center(14))

    gc.draw(canvas)
    canvas.write("tst.png")
```

This's the controller below along with Ruby script integrated.

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  def create
    post = Post.new(post_params)
    post.save

    redirect_to root_path
  end

  def show
    title1 = params["title"]
    image1 = params["image"]
    canvas = Magick::Image.new(1000, 1000) { self.background_color = "yellow" }
    gc = Magick::Draw.new
    gc.pointsize(50)
    gc.text(30, 70, title1.center(14))

    gc.draw(canvas)
    canvas.write(image1)
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def edit
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def destroy
    post = Post.find(params[:id])
    post.destroy
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  def update
    post = Post.find(params[:id])
    post.update(post_params)

    redirect_to root_path
  end

  private

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :description, :image)
  end
end
```

Finally, this is image of the error I got.

[image]

Thank you all!

Comment: Your code says `title1`, but your error message says `title`. This looks like a simple typo error, and we cannot reproduce it, because you've already fixed this mistake in the StackOverflow post.

Comment: @TomLord Sorry! wrong image

Comment: Your updated image shows that `title1`, and therefore `params["title"]`, is `nil`. This means you're not passing it as a URL parameter, like: `?title=Hello-World`. If you want this to be a required field, you can use `params.require(:title)` in the controller, and that will make it fail with status 400 (bad request) if no parameter is provided.

Comment: What is the solution then? thanks

Comment: I already told you -- If you are looking for a variable called `params["title"]`, then you need to supply that parameter in the URL. For example, if this page is `localhost:3000/posts/12345` then you need to load it with parameters like: `localhost:3000/posts/12345?title=Hello-World&image=my-awesome-filename.png`

Comment: I got what are you saying! Is there another way beside loading parameters manually? I wanna know how use and integrate Ruby script like rmagic in Ruby on Rails!

Comment: How do you **want** the parameters to be set?? Your rails code says "read them from the URL", so that's exactly how you must supply them. The original script just hardcodes the values (`text = "Text"`, `canvas.write("tst.png")`). If you want the rails script to behave exactly like the original script, then hardcode the values.

Comment: Great! I see what are you saying! what the simplest way to hardcode the values in rails? pardon me for the naive question! I am new to Rails and Ruby in general!